# flex air datagrid setfocus cell by cell

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I have a datagrid with custom itemRenderer. Now I need to setfocus int the grid cell by cell. For that I Googled & got a way i.e

```
var findrowindex:int = 0;

//nextButton Click Handler
var focusedCell: Object = new Object();
focusedCell. columnIndex = 3;
focusedCell. rowIndex = findrowindex;
dg.editedItemPosition = focusedCell; 
dg.validateNow( );
findrowindex++;
```

Using this I am able to get focus in a cell but the focus is not moving from one cell to another.
Pls suggest me where I am going wrong or suggest me any ther way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you set editable=true for those columns where you want to edit. you can move the focus by tab key. use itemEditor instead of itemRenderer. if you want the same look and feel while focus is in and focus is out. use combination of itemRenderer and itemEditor
Regards,
Arivu